# Find minimum sum that cannot be formed

Tags: algorithm, minimum

Given positive integers from 1 to N where **N can go upto 10^9**. Some K integers from these given integers are missing. **K can be at max 10^5 elements**. I need to find the minimum sum that can't be formed from remaining N-K elements in an efficient way.

Example; say we have N=5 it means we have {1,2,3,4,5} and let K=2 and missing elements are: {3,5} then remaining array is now {1,2,4} the minimum sum that can't be formed from these remaining elements is 8 because :

```
1=1
2=2
3=1+2
4=4
5=1+4
6=2+4
7=1+2+4
```

So how to find this un-summable minimum?

I know how to find this if i can store all the remaining elements by this approach:

We can use something similar to Sieve of Eratosthenes, used to find primes. Same idea, but with different rules for a different purpose.

1. Store the numbers from 0 to the sum of all the numbers, and cross off 0.
2. Then take numbers, one at a time, without replacement.
3. When we take the number Y, then cross off every number that is Y plus some previously-crossed off number.
4. When we have done this for every number that is remaining, the smallest un-crossed-off number is our answer.

However, its space requirement is high. Can there be a better and faster way to do this?

Comment: I don't know, but a quick and dirty initial check is obviously: if '1' missing, return '1'; if '2' missing, return '2';

Comment: This is a problem from an active contest: http://www.codechef.com/JAN15/problems/CLPERM

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is cheating at an active contest:  http://www.codechef.com/JAN15/problems/CLPERM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an O(sort(K))-time algorithm.

Let 1 ≤ x<sub>1</sub> ≤ x<sub>2</sub> ≤ … ≤ x<sub>m</sub> be the integers *not* missing from the set. For all i from 0 to m, let y<sub>i</sub> = x<sub>1</sub> + x<sub>2</sub> + … + x<sub>i</sub> be the partial sum of the first i terms. If it exists, let j be the least index such that y<sub>j</sub> + 1 < x<sub>j+1</sub>; otherwise, let j = m. It is possible to show via induction that the minimum sum that cannot be made is y<sub>j</sub> + 1 (the hypothesis is that, for all i from 0 to j, the numbers x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, …, x<sub>i</sub> can make all of the sums from 0 to y<sub>i</sub> and no others).

To handle the fact that the *missing* numbers are specified, there is an optimization that handles several consecutive numbers in constant time. I'll leave it as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Let X be a bitvector initialized to zero. For each number Ni you set X = (X | X << Ni) | Ni. (i.e. you can make Ni and you can increase any value you could make previously by Ni).

This will set a '1' for every value you can make.

Running time is linear in N, and bitvector operations are fast.

```
process 1: X = 00000001
process 2: X = (00000001 | 00000001 << 2) | (00000010) = 00000111
process 4: X = (00000111 | 00000111 << 4) | (00001000) = 01111111
```

First number you can't make is 8.

Comment: Please provide some pseudocode.Am not getting what you are trying to say.As what is X , Ni is hard to understand without some pseudocode

Comment: Still not getting what you are trying

Comment: I'm suggesting using bitwise operations. Also, are you sure linear is too slow? How fast do you need this to be?

Comment: @DalveGalvin O(KlogK) at max.And yes linear in N is slow in this case.Also am not getting your approach are you just taking bitvector in place of array to store the elements ?

Comment: @user How fast do you think your sieve method is?

Comment: I don't know exactly but for large N it take huge time.Can you post a function or so to clearify your approach.Because i think your approach is not linear but better than that.So perhaps it may work

Comment: @user My approach is linear. Just loop through the numbers in N-K and apply the bitvector ops.

Comment: Then it wont work.Because we need not loop over all the elements as you can see we are provided 1 to N elements.So we can take this advantage

Comment: How to store 10^9 elements is issue.

Comment: You don't need to. Just store the ones you're skipping

Comment: Store your K elements in a hash. Loop from 1 to N, and skip processing when you get to an element in K.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my O(K lg K) approach. I didn't test it very much because of lazy-overflow, sorry about that. If it works for you, I can explain the idea:

```
const int MAXK = 100003;

int n, k;
int a[MAXK];

long long sum(long long a, long long b) { // sum of elements from a to b
  return max(0ll, b * (b + 1) / 2 - a * (a - 1) / 2);
}

void answer(long long ans) {
  cout << ans << endl;
  exit(0);
}

int main() 
{
    cin >> n >> k;
  for (int i = 1; i <= k; ++i) {
    cin >> a[i];
  }

  a[0] = 0;
  a[k+1] = n+1;

  sort(a, a+k+2);

  long long ans = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i <= k+1; ++i) {
    // interval of existing numbers [lo, hi]
    int lo = a[i-1] + 1;
    int hi = a[i] - 1;

    if (lo <= hi && lo > ans + 1)
      break;

    ans += sum(lo, hi);
  }

  answer(ans + 1);
}
```

**EDIT**: well, thanks God @DavidEisenstat in his answer wrote the description of the approach I used, so I don't have to write it. Basically, what he mentions as exercise is not adding the "existing numbers" one by one, but all at the same time. Before this,you just need to check if some of them breaks the invariant, which can be done using binary search. Hope it helped.

**EDIT2**: as @DavidEisenstat pointed in the comments, the binary search is not needed, since only the first number in every interval of existing numbers can break the invariant. Modified the code accordingly.

Comment: :) you are so damn right. I'm really dumb these days. I will edit the code. Thanks.

Comment: See the edit: the code was updated. As I said, I didn't check it. If this is a problem from some programming contest or some online judge, post also the reference. Now the answer for that case is 29, but I don't know if it's the correct one.

Comment: 10^9 can fit int 32 bits (even 31), so any (signed) 32-bit integer type will do (no need for `long long` types)

Comment: 10^9 can fit in 32-bit, but the answer to the problem may not.